# DB2 Cardinality

Tags: db2, statistics, db2-luw, index-statistics

In my tables, I have many **statistics** with -1 and I want to know how can I enforce DB2 to calculate these values.

```sql
   Select FIRSTKEYCARD, FIRST2KEYCARD, FIRST3KEYCARD, FIRST4KEYCARD, FULLKEYCARD
    FROM SYSCAT.INDEXES
    WHERE (TABSCHEMA = SCHEMA_NAME) AND
          (TABNAME   = TABLE_NAME)
```

My collection statistics look like

```
 Automatic maintenance                      (AUTO_MAINT) = OFF
   Automatic database backup            (AUTO_DB_BACKUP) = OFF
   Automatic table maintenance          (AUTO_TBL_MAINT) = OFF
     Automatic runstats                  (AUTO_RUNSTATS) = OFF
       Real-time statistics            (AUTO_STMT_STATS) = OFF
       Statistical views              (AUTO_STATS_VIEWS) = OFF
       Automatic sampling                (AUTO_SAMPLING) = OFF
       Automatic column group statistics (AUTO_CG_STATS) = OFF
     Automatic reorganization               (AUTO_REORG) = OFF
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the [`runstats`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statistics-collecting-index) command?

Comment: Not in detail, but I use it always on this way
`RUNSTATS ON TABLE MY_TABLE with distribution on key columns and detailed indexes all`, but as can I see it is not sufficient

Comment: Have you runstats a table and still get -1 for that table?

Answer (score 0):

If you ran runstats on a table you should get updated statistics. Example:

```
db2 "create table db2inst1.test(x int not null, y int not null, primary key (x,y))"
db2 "Select FIRSTKEYCARD, FIRST2KEYCARD, FIRST3KEYCARD, FIRST4KEYCARD, FULLKEYCARD
 FROM SYSCAT.INDEXES
 WHERE TABSCHEMA = 'DB2INST1' and TABNAME = 'TEST'"

FIRSTKEYCARD         FIRST2KEYCARD        FIRST3KEYCARD        FIRST4KEYCARD        FULLKEYCARD         
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
              -1                   -1                   -1                   -1                   -1

db2 runstats on table db2inst1.test with distribution and sampled detailed indexes all
db2 "Select FIRSTKEYCARD, FIRST2KEYCARD, FIRST3KEYCARD, FIRST4KEYCARD, FULLKEYCARD
FROM SYSCAT.INDEXES
WHERE TABSCHEMA = 'DB2INST1' and TABNAME = 'TEST'"

FIRSTKEYCARD         FIRST2KEYCARD        FIRST3KEYCARD        FIRST4KEYCARD        FULLKEYCARD         
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
               0                    0                   -1                   -1                    0
```

As expected FIRSTKEYCARD, FIRST2KEYCARD and FULLKEYCARD is updated

You may want to have a look at automatic statistics collection. Example:

```
 Automatic maintenance                      (AUTO_MAINT) = ON
   Automatic database backup            (AUTO_DB_BACKUP) = OFF
   Automatic table maintenance          (AUTO_TBL_MAINT) = ON
     Automatic runstats                  (AUTO_RUNSTATS) = ON
       Real-time statistics            (AUTO_STMT_STATS) = ON
       Statistical views              (AUTO_STATS_VIEWS) = ON
       Automatic sampling                (AUTO_SAMPLING) = ON
       Automatic column group statistics (AUTO_CG_STATS) = ON
     Automatic reorganization               (AUTO_REORG) = OFF
```

Comment: Hmm, how can I ask or select for printing out these parameters for automatic statistics collection?

Comment: Ok just figured out https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=commands-get-database-configuration

Comment: I have updated with my configuraiton for the automatic statistics. It is anything wrong valued their?

Comment: Do you still not see updated statistics if you do rustats on table?

Comment: It is updated. But do you recommend some of the parameters above.

Comment: You will have to make your own decision, but the settings I showed works very well for us. I prefer to schedule the backups and I don't use automatic reorgs, other than that everything is automatic